# perform simultaneous operations based on the some conditions in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I have  to perform set of operations based on some conditions like fetching data from database which takes approximately 10 seconds per query (ConnectedDevices.getAllDetails() takes 10 to execute and return result).

this may be similar to below question 
[optimized way to search a device ip address within a range in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357266/optimized-way-to-search-a-device-ip-address-within-a-range-in-iphone) 
but in my case i need to perform operations in batches as shown in below code :

```
var isConditionTrue = false
var numProcessed = 0
let dbQueue = dispatch_queue_create("dbQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

// case 1
    for i in 1...10 {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY.value), 0)) {
            let eachDBValue = ConnectedDevices.getAllDetails(i)

                dispatch_async(dbQueue) {
                    if !eachDBValue {
                        numProcessed++
                    }
                }
            }
        }


// case 2
for i in 11...20 {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY.value), 0)) {
            let eachDBValue = ConnectedDevices.getAllDetails(i)

                dispatch_async(dbQueue) {
                    if !eachDBValue {
                        numProcessed++
                    }
                }
            }
        }


// case 3
for i in 21...30 {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY.value), 0)) {
            let eachDBValue = ConnectedDevices.getAllDetails(i)

                dispatch_async(dbQueue) {
                    if !ieachDBValue {
                        numProcessed++
                    }
                }
            }
        }


// case 4
for i in 31...40 {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY.value), 0)) {
            let eachDBValue = ConnectedDevices.getAllDetails(i)

                dispatch_async(dbQueue) {
                    if !eachDBValue {
                        numProcessed++
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So if in case 1, if result is false for 1  to 10 then it should go to case 2. If result is true for any instance.. it should not execute any case 2,3,4.

Similarly for case 2, if result is false for 1 to 10 then it should go to case 3 else it should stop.
All this i need to do based on the conditions.

Comment: I don't understand why you write `for i in 11...20` instead of `for i in 0...9`. The same question is valid for every `for` in your code.

Comment: @ appzYourLife - bcoz i have scenario like that.. instead of looping in one shot from 0... 40 i need to break it and work in sets of operation.

Comment: There's no difference of course since the `i` is not used.

Comment: You are performing several calls to `ConnectedDevices.getAllDetails()`. Do you expect a different result after `n` calls?

Comment: @appzYourLife - my mistake i forgot .. we will be using i and now  updated code in the question.

Comment: Another question, looking at your code it seems that `ConnectedDevices.getAllDetails(i)` returns a `Bool` value. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution

### The fake ConnectedDevices class

This is the fake class I created to test your scenario. As you can see the method `getAllDetails` does simulate your database access.
It waits for 10 seconds and then returns `true` only if the input parameter is `40`. This way we can test this code on the worst case scenario since all the call will need to be done.

```
class ConnectedDevices {
    class func getAllDetails(i:Int) -> Bool {
        sleep(10)
        return i == 40
    }
}
```

### The Loader class

This is the class that will interact with `Grand Central Dispatch`.

```
class Loader {
    private var numProcessed = 0
    private let dbQueue = dispatch_queue_create("dbQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    private let utilityQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)

    func search(completion:(result:Int?)->()) {
        dispatch_async(utilityQueue) {
            for group in [1, 11, 21, 31] {
                if let indexFound = self.search10(group) {
                    completion(result: indexFound)
                    return
                }
            }
            completion(result: nil)
        }
    }

    private func search10(startingIndex:Int) -> Int? {
        var indexFound : Int?
        dispatch_apply(10, utilityQueue) { (delta) -> () in
            let found = ConnectedDevices.getAllDetails(startingIndex + delta)
            dispatch_sync(self.dbQueue) {
                self.numProcessed++ // this is increased anyway
                if found {
                    indexFound = startingIndex + delta
                }
            }
        }
        return indexFound
    }
}
```

### search10(startingIndex:Int)

This synchronous method receives an `Int` as param and executes 10 concurrent calls to `ConnectedDevices.getAllDetails`. Each call is performed adding `startingIndex` to `delta` (`delta` goes from `0` to `9`).

The result is synchronously put into a synchronous queue where `numProcessed` is safely increased. If `found` is `true` then the "winning" index (`startingIndex + delta`) is returned.

If `found` never becomes `true` then `nil` is returned.

### search()

This is an `asych` method. It's a simple `for loop` where the `group` variables is populated with `1`, then `11`, then `21` and finally `31`.

Each time `search10` is invoked. If it does return an `Int` the value is passed to the `completion` closure, otherwise the loop does continue.

If the 4 cycles are performed with no value returned from `search10` then `nil` is passed to the `completion` closure.

### Usage

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        debugPrintln("Begin: \(NSDate())")
        Loader().search { (result) -> () in
            debugPrintln(result)
            debugPrintln("End: \(NSDate())")
        }
    }    
}
```

### Test

40 sequential calls to `ConnectedDevices.getAllDetails(...)` would require `40 * 10 = 400 seconds`.

In my iPhone Simulator without any optimization enabled this code requires about `120 seconds`.

Hope this is what you need.

### P.S.

1. Please note that I am increasing `numProcessed` also if the current result is `true`.
2. I did not found the purpose of `isConditionTrue` so I removed it.